How to know when a FeatureCollection has been edited?
I want to export the WDPA at a specific resolution to simplify some of my downstream processes. This image will need to be refactored on regular basis when the source ee.FeatureCollection is updated.
Is there a way to check when a ee.FeatureCollection has been last modified in GEE ? for example in the following dataset:
ee.FeatureCollection("WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons") 


There is a version associated with the collection. I haven't checked, but it would make sense if that changes when the collection updates. ee.Dictionary(ee.Algorithms.Describe(collection)).getNumber('version')
